# I want to download files using SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, model-view-controller

An attempt was made to implement file downloads through the SpringBoot MVC structure. There is no error, it says it has run normally, but the download does not proceed.

All information about the file is entered correctly, and also the path and name of the file are entered correctly.
I'd like to know why the download doesn't proceed even though there's no error.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
@PostMapping("/fileDownload")
    public void fileDownload(@RequestBody BoardFileDTO dto,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        //File contains all stored paths, names, and extensions
        Path fileNamePath = Paths.get(Directory + dto.getFile_save_name()).toAbsolutePath();
        
        String filename = dto.getFile_save_name(); //The name of the saved file
        String downname = dto.getFile_name();      //The name of the file to be saved

        if (filename == null || "".equals(filename)) {
            filename = downname;
        }
         
        try {
            String browser = request.getHeader("User-Agent"); 
            //File Encoding
            if (browser.contains("MSIE") || browser.contains("Trident")
                    || browser.contains("Chrome")) {
                filename = URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+",
                        "%20");
            } else {
                filename = new String(filename.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            System.out.println("UnsupportedEncodingException");
        }
        System.out.println(fileNamePath);
        File file1 = new File(fileNamePath.toString());
        if (!file1.exists()) {
            return ;
        }
         
        // Specifying a File  
        response.setContentType("application/octer-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary;");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
        try {
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileNamePath.toString());
 
            int ncount = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[512];
 
            while ((ncount = fis.read(bytes)) != -1 ) {
                os.write(bytes, 0, ncount);
            }
            fis.close();
            os.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do `fileNamePath.toString()` to convert a `Path` to something else, use the proper factory methods. You also already create a `File` reuse that to get the `FileInputStream`. Instead of your `while` loop use the `StreamUtils` from Spring to copy the input to the output (or the java `Files` class). Finally your `contentType` is wrong I strongly suggest to use the constants from `MediaType` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit convoluted imho. A couple of issues I see with your code

1. Using `Path.toString` to convert to a `File`, use the proper factory methods instead or use `java.nio.Files` to check the existence.
2. Your content-type is wrong `application/octer-stream` isn't a known content-type (you probably want `application/octet-stream`.
3. Copying from a `Path` or `File` is better done with either the `StreamUtils` from Spring or the `java.nio.Files` class (if you already have a `Path` use that).

```java
@PostMapping("/fileDownload")
public void fileDownload(@RequestBody BoardFileDTO dto, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    //File contains all stored paths, names, and extensions
    Path fileNamePath = Paths.get(Directory, dto.getFile_save_name()).toAbsolutePath();

    if (!Files.exists(fileNamePath)) {
        return;
    }

    String filename = determineFilename(dto, request);

    // Specifying a File
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
    response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary;");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
    try {
        Files.copy(fileNamePath, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
    }
}

private static String determineFilename(BoardFileDTO dto, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String filename = dto.getFile_save_name(); //The name of the saved file

    if (filename == null || "".equals(filename)) {
        filename = dto.getFile_name();
    }

    String browser = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
    //File Encoding
    if (browser.contains("MSIE") || browser.contains("Trident") || browser.contains("Chrome")) {
        filename = URLEncoder.encode(filename, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
    } else {
        filename = new String(filename.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    }
    return filename;
}
```

It would write it something like that. As you have a path use the `java.nio.Files` to check for existence and copying. Use constants for mediatypes and charsets.

Your error handling is quite basic (I would say non-existing and at least not proper) as the processing just stops and returns an empty 200 to the client. No information what so ever.

I took the liberty to factor out the logic to determine the filename, which should make your code more readable.